# How can I Rescale a ColorFunction on a 3D plot

Tags: plotting, color

> I'll like to know if there is a way to do this colorfunction scaling on 3D plots

```
    Plot[0.8 Sin[x] + 0.2, {x, 0, 3 \[Pi]}, 
ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#2, {0.2, 1}]] &), 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

> then we got the color function scaled

[image]

> I'll like to do the same in 3D on this case

```
 Plot3D[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, 0, 3 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 3 \[Pi]}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#2, {0.2, 1}]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

> But something terrible happens, it is scaled on x and y but not on z
>   [image]

Comment: I thik that I solve it using this  Plot3D[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, 0, 3 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 3 \[Pi]}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, (ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, {0.2, 1}]] &)[
    z]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False]

Comment: use `(ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#3, {0.2, 1}]] &)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Plot3D[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, 0, 3 π}, {y, 0, 3 π},
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#3, {0.2, 1}]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

An alternative form is `ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[z, {0.2, 1}]]]`.

Alternatively, you can specify the range of the color function in `ColorData` and  omit the function argument (the default color gradient direction is `z`):

```
Plot3D[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, 0, 3 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 3 \[Pi]},
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0.2, 1}}], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

> same picture